# CSRF protection globally on Zend Framework1 application

Tags: php, zend-framework, csrf

I need to add CSRF protection on ZF1 project globally. I know how to add for single form but I have already created lots of form in the project. So to do it for each and every form is very tedious and very time consuming job. I need a plug-in or any library for ZF1 that add a layer on top of every form element and receives post request with CSRF token on every form.
Any logic to implement this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

just extend the `Zend_Form` with your own `CustomForm` and add the csrf field creation in the `init()` function.

Comment: +1 proper oop solution that shouldn't take very long to implement even if all his forms are Zend_Form.

Comment: @konradwww, Its creating CSRF field but I need to verify token in each form post controller's action. How can I achieve it globally in one place?

Comment: if you add it to your form class it schould automatically validate by isValid() method.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://blog.jverkamp.com/2014/01/13/csrf-protection-injection-with-jquery-and-zend/) explains how to add CSRF as an after thought.

Basically you need two things:

1. JavaScript to catch ajax posts and form post events, where you inject a CSRF code into the form data before submit.
2. A preDispatch plugin in Zend that checks the CSRF token on POST requests.